# A binary column created in the PySpark dataframe cannot be used as a filter?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using PySpark to create an additional BinaryColumn in my dataframe and then using it to filter the dataframe. This process is showing an error.

1. Data:

[Click here to see the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7OKk.png)

2. Created the Binary Column:

[Click here to see the Binary Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PwHM.png)

[Click here to see the Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C80wO.png)

3. Filter and the error:

[Click here to see the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSFhw.png)

Answer (score 0):

try using `filter` function

```
df_filter = df_bc.filter(col('binary_col') == 'false')
df_filter.show()
```

Comment: Since the column 'binary_col' has binary data (refer schema), thus we can use this column directly as a filter. However; it is throwing an error . My question is why it is throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `binary_col` to **`df_bc`** dataframe not to `df_`.

Try to access binary_col from `df_bc` dataframe,

```
df_filter=df_bc.where(df_bc.binary_col)
df_filter.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Shu.     If I chain the methods then it still gives me error. Does it follows the SQL like chain  of execution of commands?                                                            
 df_.withColumn("BinaryColumn", df_.B > 5).where(df_.BinaryColumn).show()

Comment: Yes, in the above case **filter clause** will be executed first and fails as we don't have the `BinaryColumn` in **`df_`** dataframe.